# Mysql single column result to multiple column result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a MySQL query, the problem is I have the following table:

```
id, rep, val dates 

1 rep1 200 06/01/2014 
2 rep2 300 06/01/2014 
3 rep3 400 06/01/2014 
4 rep4 500 06/01/2014 
5 rep5 100 06/01/2014 
6 rep1 200 02/06/2014 
7 rep2 300 02/06/2014 
8 rep3 900 02/06/2014 
9 rep4 700 02/06/2014 
10 rep5 600 02/06/2014
```

and I want a result like this:

```
rep 01/06/2014 02/06/2014 
rep1 200 200 
rep2 300 300 
rep3 400 900 
rep4 500 700 
rep5 100 600
```

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the val for each of the dates.

Assuming the dates you are interested in are fixed then you can do that as follows. For output date column you check of the row matches the date for that column. If so you use the value of *val* , if not you just use 0. Then you sum all the resulting values, grouping by rep. I have assumed a fixed format of date.

```
SELECT rep, SUM(IF(dates='2014/06/01'), val, 0) AS '2014/06/01', SUM(IF(dates='2014/06/02'), val, 0) AS '2014/06/02'
FROM sometable
GROUP BY rep
```

Or if you just wanted the highest val for each day

```
SELECT rep, MAX(IF(dates='2014/06/01'), val, 0) AS '2014/06/01', MAX(IF(dates='2014/06/02'), val, 0) AS '2014/06/02'
FROM sometable
GROUP BY rep
```

If the number of dates is variable then not really a direct way to do it (as the number of resulting columns would vary). It would be easiest to do this manly in your calling script based on the following, giving you one row per rep / possible date with a sum of the values of val for that rep / date combination:-

```
SELECT rep, sub0.dates, SUM(IF(sometable.dates=sub0.dates), val, 0)
FROM sometable
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT dates 
    FROM sometable
) sub0
GROUP BY rep, sub0.dates
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the most recent row for each rep.  Here is an approach that often performs well:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.repid = t.repid and
                        t2.id > t.id
                 );
```

This transforms the problem to:  "Get me the rows in table `t` where there is no other row with the same `repid` and a larger `id`."  That is the same logic as getting the last one, just convoluted a bit to help the database know what to do.

For performance reasons, an index on `t(repid, id)` is helpful.